# How can I echo out each character of a string?

Tags: php, strlen

This is my code but it only counts the character not displaying it.

```
$cnt = strlen('hello');

for($a=0; $a<=$cnt; $a++){
echo $cnt.'<br>';
}
```

output is just 5 5 5 5 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strlen gives you length of that word. That length you store in $cnt. That means you just print 5 times length of that word. The correct way is this

```
$cnt = 'hello';

for($a=0; $a < strlen($cnt); $a++){
   echo $cnt[$a].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to this :

```
$str = 'hello' ;
$cnt = strlen($str);

for($a=0; $a<$cnt; $a++){
   echo $str[$a].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you please explain your answer? That way, those who come across this question will understand *why* your solution works rather than being tempted to copy/paste it without learning anything.